# How to retrieve an image from static folder using javascript and django

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have trouble trying to get an image from static folder. When I pass the image in the html it works. here is my code

```
<div id="dirs" class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 540px;">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="{% static 'PERDNI/09401576.jpg' %}" class="card-img" alt="..."/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Datos personales</h5>
                <p class="card-text">This is a wider card.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the generated html in the browser inspector:
[image]

In other hand, when I generate the html from a javascript file, it doesn't work, The image doesn't appear but the other part of the html yes. Here is my code

```
var datahtml='<div class="row no-gutters"><div class="col-md-4">';
datahtml+='<img src="{% static '
datahtml+="'PERDNI/09401576.jpg'"
datahtml+=' %}" class="card-img" alt="My image"/>'
datahtml+='</div><div class="col-md-8"><div class="card-body">'
datahtml+='<h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>'
datahtml+='<p class="card-text">Hello</p>'
datahtml+='</div></div></div>'
document.getElementById("dirs").innerHTML=datahtml
```

This is the other generated html in the browser inspector:
[image]

What would be the problem, I was thinking in the quotes however I tried in many ways and It haven't worked yet. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you see in the first generated html is the content returned by your django backend code after rendering your template. In your javascript code (is it client side or server side using something like node.js?), the html you are creating is using the html template, which is shouldn't

Comment: try like this `datahtml+='<img src="{% static 'PERDNI/09401576.jpg' %}" >'`

Comment: I tried datahtml+='<img src="{% static 'PERDNI/09401576.jpg' %}" >' however It didn't work. Thank you so much anyway.

Comment: code `{% static .. %}` is Python code and it can't work in JavaScript. In JavaScript you have to use directly `/static/PERDNI/09401576.jpg`. Eventually you could use `{% static .. %}` is Python (using Django's templates) to genearate file with JavaScript - and then this file will have  `/static/PERDNI/09401576.jpg`